# How do I install MySQL on Occidentalis?

Tags: raspbian, software-installation, occidentalis, mysql

I cannot find any guides on how to install MySQL on a Raspberry Pi running [Occidentalis 0.2](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-raspberry-pi-educational-linux-distro/occidentalis-v0-dot-2); Occidentalis is a Raspbian derivative.

I cannot use apt-get to install it even after running `apt-get update`. I guess I'll need to compile MySQL myself. What is the experience with doing this?

This is what I tried:

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ sudo apt-get install mysql
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package mysql
```

Comment: It installs using apt-get on Raspbian.  Unless you have a specific reason for using Occidentalis it might be easier to just use that.

Comment: If you need a database on Occidentalis, use `sqlite` instead. I'm reasonably certain it will keep up on a low load.

Comment: @Kibbee: Occidentalis is based on Raspbian so it should use the same repos. If it's available in Raspian, it should be available in Occidentalis too, unless something is broken.

Comment: @AlexChamberlain: MySQL should also be able to work with quite low resources. And SQLite is very simple and lacks a lot of features of true RDBMs so it might not be suitable for many workloads.

Comment: maybe im doing something wrong. edited question with my install steps

Comment: try this instead sudo apt-get install mysql-server mysql-client

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Easy answer:

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

You just forgot the `-server` string!!

Good luck!

Comment: damn it... always editing both my answers and my questions ;)

Comment: Don't forget that you can use `apt-cache search foo` to search for package names if you are not sure of them.

Answer (score 2):

Occidentalis, Raspbian and Debian divide the MySQL functionality into 2 packages: `mysql-server` and `mysql-client`. They can be installed using `apt-get install`, which should be run as `root`.